# When using foreign keys, getting "User.DepartmentDepartmentId" instead of "User.DepartmentId"

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

In using Sequelize cli/js in trying to recreate the database structure, I am getting strange behavior when joining tables with foreign keys.  It seems to be adding the model name in the foreign key, even when I specifically assign one.  The dialect is MSSQL

**User Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    UserId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    FirstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    LastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    Username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    Email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    Password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    OfficePhone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    DepartmentId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    ContractorId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    IsActive: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1
    },
    CreatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    UpdatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    DeletedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  }, {
    paranoid: true,
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'CreatedAt',
    updatedAt: 'UpdatedAt',
    deletedAt: 'DeletedAt',
    tableName: 'AppUsers',
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: ['Username']
      }
    ]
  });
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.belongsTo(models.Department, {
      targetKey: 'DepartmentId'
    });
    User.belongsTo(models.Contractor, {
      targetKey: 'ContractorId'
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

**Department Model**

```
  const Department = sequelize.define('Department', {
    DepartmentId: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    DepartmentName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    CreatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    UpdatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    DeletedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  }, {
    paranoid: true,
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'CreatedAt',
    updatedAt: 'UpdatedAt',
    deletedAt: 'DeletedAt',
    tableName: 'AppDepartments',
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: ['DepartmentName']
      }
    ]
  });
  Department.associate = function(models) {
    Department.hasMany(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'DepartmentId'
    });
  };
  return Department;
};
```

**Find All**

```
exports.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
  const showDeleted = ( req.headers.showdeleted == 'false' ); 
  await User.findAll({
    attributes: ['UserId', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Username', 'Email', 'OfficePhone', 'IsActive', 'DeletedAt'],
    include: [
      { model: Department, attributes: ['DepartmentName'] },
      { model: Contractor, attributes: ['ContractorName'] }
    ],
    paranoid: showDeleted,
    order: [
      ['LastName', 'ASC']
    ]
  })
    .then(results => {
      res.status(200).send(results);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
};
```

**Generated Query**

```
SELECT [User].[UserId], 
[User].[FirstName], 
[User].[LastName], 
[User].[Username], 
[User].[Email], 
[User].[OfficePhone], 
[User].[IsActive], 
[User].[DeletedAt], 
[Department].[DepartmentId] AS [Department.DepartmentId], 
[Department].[DepartmentName] AS [Department.DepartmentName], 
[Contractor].[ContractorId] AS [Contractor.ContractorId], 
[Contractor].[ContractorName] AS [Contractor.ContractorName] 
FROM [DrxAppUsers] AS [User] 

LEFT OUTER JOIN [DrxAppDepartments] AS [Department] ON [User].[DepartmentDepartmentId] = [Department].[DepartmentId] AND ([Department].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) 

LEFT OUTER JOIN [DrxAppContractors] AS [Contractor] ON [User].[ContractorContractorId] = [Contractor].[ContractorId] AND ([Contractor].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) WHERE ([User].[DeletedAt] IS NULL) ORDER BY [User].[LastName] ASC;
```

As you can see above, it's trying to join to "User.DepartmentDepartmentId" (and also User.ContractorContractorId as ContractorId is a foreign key as well).  Why is it doing that and how do I fix it?  I've tried many different options and what not with the foreign keys, and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: why you have added tableName: 'AppDepartments', after deletedAt ? is it necessary ?

Comment: @mike please see the answer below which solves your problem

Comment: @VyasArpit - I am forced to a table naming convention.  It doesn't matter where tableName sits in the object.  For my own reading purposes, that's just where I put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the naming of the **foreign key** when creating your associations. If not specified, it defaults to the name of target + primary key of target. So for you that is `DepartmentDepartmentId` and you want `DepartmentId`

```
User.belongsTo(models.Department, {
  targetKey: 'DepartmentId',
  foreignKey: 'DepartmentId' // the key in your source table
});
```

[Ref](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-belongsTo)

Comment: Yes, that helped.  Thank you.  I also added "as" to the associations as well, which made it even nicer to associate models and queries.  Thank you!